# $\lnot \exists x (\forall y (\alpha)\land \forall z(\beta) )\;$ is logically equivalent to which one of these?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

These are the options:

1. $\forall x(\exists z(\lnot \beta)\rightarrow \forall y(\alpha))$
2. $\forall x(\forall z(\beta)\to \exists y(\lnot\alpha))$
3. $\forall x(\forall y(\alpha)\to \exists z(\lnot \beta))$
4. $\forall x(\exists y(\lnot \alpha )\to \exists z(\lnot \beta))$

How will I conclude the expression?
Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? What do you know?

Comment: My Bad.Frankly nothing, i don't know from where to start.

Comment: So do you know that $\neg\exists x(\phi(x))$ is equivalent to $\forall x(\neg\phi(x))$? Or is the problem with turning $\land$ into $\implies$?

Comment: What is $z$ above?

Comment: Note that $\neg\exists x P$ is equivalent to $\forall x\neg P$ and $P\to Q$ is equivalent to $\neg(P\land \neg Q)$.

Comment: yes exactly, how to convert ∧ into ⟹

Comment: $a \lor b$ is equivalent to $\lnot a \to b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four things you'll want to use here (and four things you'll need to know here and moving forward):

$\lnot \exists x P(x)$ is equivalent to $\forall x \lnot P(x)$.

Likewise, $\lnot \forall x P(x)$ is equivalent to $\exists x \lnot P(x)$.

$\lnot (P \land Q)$ is equivalent to $\lnot P \lor \lnot Q$

$\lnot P \lor Q \equiv P\rightarrow Q$.

$$\begin{align} \lnot\exists x\,(\forall y(\alpha) \land \forall z (\beta) & \equiv \forall x\,\Big(\lnot[\forall y(\alpha) \land \forall z (\beta)]\Big) \\ \\ 
&\equiv \forall x\Big(\lnot \forall y(\alpha) \lor \lnot \forall z(\beta)\Big)\\ \\ 
&\equiv \forall x\Big( \forall y(\alpha) \rightarrow \lnot \forall z(\beta)\Big)\\ \\
&\equiv \quad \cdots\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Formulas for logical equivalence + DE Morgan's laws for quantifiers. All Efforts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We know that: $$\sim(\forall x, P(x))\equiv \exists x, \sim P(x),~~~~\forall x, \sim P(x))\equiv \sim(\exists x,  P(x))$$ and $$P(x)\to Q(x)\equiv \sim P(x)\vee Q(x)$$ so $$\sim[\exists x\left(\forall y~\alpha~\wedge~\forall z~\beta\right)]\equiv\forall x(\exists y (\sim\alpha)~\vee~\exists z(\sim\beta))$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a relationship between the universal and existential quantifiers.
The proposition $\forall x(\phi(x))$ says that for every $x$ the formula $\phi(x)$ is true.
The negation of that statement would read

> It is not the case that for every $x$ the formula $\phi(x)$ is true

Which you could interpret as

> There is an $x$ such that it is not the case that the formula $\phi(x)$ is true.

Knowing that you can interchange the quantifiers like that (and negating their formula) can you do the rest of this problem?

Comment: thanks.i am trying.If i can ,i'll answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You must use , in turn, three "rules" :

*(i)* interrelationship between quantifiers, i.e.

> $\lnot \exists x$ is "interchangable" with $\forall x \lnot$

and

> $\lnot \forall x$ is "interchangable" with $\exists x \lnot$

*(ii)* De Morgan laws, i.e.

> $\lnot (p \land q)$ is equivalent to $(\lnot p \lor \lnot q)$

and

> $\lnot (p \lor q)$ is equivalent to $(\lnot p \land \lnot q)$

*(iii)*

definition of $\rightarrow$ in terms of $\lor$ and $\lnot$, i.e.

> $(p \rightarrow q)$ is equivalent to $(\lnot p \lor q)$.